# How to move something on screen without other picture staying there

Tags: java

I am trying to make a 2048 game using java so for a test I will make the image move when I press space but the image that was there before stay there. I am want to how to get the image be removed for the screen without making a million of the image.

```
public void drawTile(Graphics g)
{
    BufferedImage img = Textures.getImage(new File("src//res//" + 
    getNumber() + " 2048.png"));
    if(isDraw()) 
    {
    g.drawImage(img, getX(), getY(), null);
    setDraw(false);
    Handler.removeTile(new Tiles(getNumber(), getX(), getY(), false));
    }
}
```

That is the code I am using for making the tiles and displaying them on screen.

Comment: You probably have to clear the canvas and redraw all the tiles when anything changes, or draw over (with solid color?) the region where the image was previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your method paintComponent(Graphics g)

You must call super.paintComponent(g) as the first line cause JPanels do clean the screen or call

```
 g.setColor(Colors.BLACK); // or your background
 g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Second:

```
 BufferedImage img = Textures.getImage(new File("src//res//" + getNumber() + " 2048.png"))
```

Move this line to the object constructor, you can reuse the same image instead of reloading it all times.